# Trouble creating new variable based off of existing variable

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new variable based off of an existing variable in my df.  I have run into this error before and I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Code:

```
def DEMO2(a):
    if a['DEMO']=='02-05C':
       return 'P 02-11'
    elif a['DEMO']=='65+M':
       return 'P 55-99'

merge_df['DEMO2']=merge_df.apply('DEMO2', axis=1)
```

TypeError: ("'str' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0')

I feel like there is an obvious answer that I am missing...

Comment: I don't know Pandas, but do you actually want quotes around DEMO2? You want to pass the function itself don't you? Not just it's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the DEMO2 function even .

```
merge_df['DEMO2']=merge_df.DEMO.replace({'02-05C':'P 02-11','65+M':'P 55-99'})
```

Comment: This is much quicker than using apply.  Thank you.

Comment: @nakedbird226 if it is help you , can you consider accept and upvote ?

Comment: `merge_df.replace({'DEMO': {'02-05C':'P 02-11','65+M':'P 55-99'}})` will also work.

Comment: @piRSquared this even better , will fill the none match one to NaN :-)

Comment: @nakedbird226 please using piR's answer  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well you're getting that error because of this

```
merge_df['DEMO2']=merge_df.apply('DEMO2', axis=1)
```

Should (probably) be this:

```
merge_df['DEMO2']=merge_df.apply(DEMO2, axis=1)
```